My pivot table keeps putting changing Date order halfway down in excel
I copy some data from a csv file in to an excel sheet. When I put a filter on this table in the 'Date' field from old to new it orders it correctly - no problem.
However, when I create pivot table using this data, for some utterly bizarre reason it goes from 06/10/2024 to 10/10/2024 then 9 then 8 then 7 and that's it. What has happened and how do I fix this as it's making my charts all displaced.
Row Labels
30/09/2024
01/10/2024
02/10/2024
03/10/2024
04/10/2024
05/10/2024
06/10/2024
10/10/2024
09/10/2024
08/10/2024
07/10/2024
Grand Total

Normal table before pivot
Trading Date
30/09/2024
30/09/2024
30/09/2024
30/09/2024
30/09/2024
01/10/2024
01/10/2024
01/10/2024
01/10/2024
01/10/2024
02/10/2024
02/10/2024
02/10/2024
02/10/2024
02/10/2024
03/10/2024
03/10/2024
03/10/2024
03/10/2024
03/10/2024
04/10/2024
04/10/2024
04/10/2024
04/10/2024
04/10/2024
05/10/2024
05/10/2024
05/10/2024
05/10/2024
05/10/2024
06/10/2024
06/10/2024
06/10/2024
06/10/2024
06/10/2024
07/10/2024
07/10/2024
07/10/2024
07/10/2024
07/10/2024
08/10/2024
08/10/2024
08/10/2024
08/10/2024
08/10/2024
09/10/2024
09/10/2024
09/10/2024
09/10/2024
09/10/2024
10/10/2024
10/10/2024
10/10/2024
10/10/2024
10/10/2024

Have tried changing to date format in the excel file to dd-mm-yyyy, have tried yyyy-mm-dd to but it just changes it back to dd/mm/yyyy. I haven't had an issue with it before until this date period was put in. Other date periods are fine.

Did you actually sort that field in the pivot table?

Hi Yes, I've just noticed by pivot tables haven't been sorted! They usually auto sort so was very confused. Thank you
